# Windows 7 Library View Isn't Shown for File Upload

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

When trying to upload a file in IE9, the Windows 7 library for Pictures doesn't show the correct view. Is there a hack to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are referring to the native Windows 7 file chooser, there should be a button in the top right corner of the dialog to change the view to your liking.

[image: Picture Upload]